# Is there any way to enrich kubernetes events with custom labels?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to correlate events regarding pods of the same deployment, but I'm struggling with the fact they referes only the exact pod they're related to.

`kubectl get events -o json`

I see the `metadata` object doesn't contain any `label` field.
Although, `kubectl describe events` shows `Label: <none>`.

So:

1. Events can have labels? `kubectl describe` is showing them empty just to uniform its output?
2. If events can have labels, is there any way, acting on deployment/pod annotations, to enrich events with labels?

Just in case it matters, I'm using gke.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Events contain mandatory `involvedObject` field that contains information about the object that this event is about. Two fields are especially interesting: `involvedObject.kind` and `involvedObject.name`.

You can find the events based on the objects you're interested in like this:

```
kubectl get event --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-deployment,involvedObject.kind=Deployment
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to "tag" the events of the pods related to the same deployment. This will get the events related to the deployment resource.